Host no detecta variable de constructor de component breadcrumb
Al subir mi proyecto de laravel a un host me da error de que no encuentra la varible $breadcrumbs:

Este valor viene del controlador del componente:

Asi que deberia crearse correctamente.
Esto solo me pasa al subir a un host, ya que en local funciona correctamente.
Espero que me puedan ayudar
Gracias

Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! Te sugiero leer Cómo preguntar para mejorar tu pregunta y que sea mejor recibida. También, aprovechar y hacer el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos. Luego puedes editar la pregunta para agregar/modificar la info, por ejemplo quitando capturas de pantalla del codigo y agregandolo como texto

En tu local usas windows y en el host linux? podrias dar mas detalles de tu setup local y las diferencias con el host? Creo que laravel usa el standard PSR-4, por lo que me parece raro declarar el nombre una clase en minuscula
